# SQL Insert into Only Certain Columns

Tags: java, mysql, sql, oracle

I have a database with 5 columns. The first column is the ID which will be automatically incremented everytime a new row is added using this statement.

```
ALTER TABLE help MODIFY COLUMN id INT auto_increment
```

So, because this will automatically increment I dont want to set it as anything, because of this I thought of this statement. However, it leaves a syntax error. Any ideas why?

```
   String update = "INSERT INTO help(" + name + ", " + area + ", " + date + ", " + message + ") VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)";
        try {
            connection = plugin.getHikari().getConnection();
            // Inserting into the table
            statement = connection.prepareStatement(update);
            // Replace the '?' with the actual information
            statement.setString(1, name);
            statement.setString(2, area);
            statement.setString(3, date);
            statement.setString(4, message);
            statement.execute();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Thanks, 
- Nicster

PS: Yes, this is day 2 of my SQL adventure D:

Comment: Take a step back. You need to find a good sql tutorial. SO can be a resource for specific problems but I think you haven't grasped the fundamentals of SQL yet. Fundamentals first, then make it happen in Java. Your code in the question doesn't make sense and isn't complete. Erick and Gordon have given you the answer to your problem but your response has been "it still doesn't work". In what way do their answers not work?

Answer (score 3):

You can parameterize *values* in a query, but not the names of columns and tables.  So, you need to write:

```
String update = "INSERT INTO help(name, area, date, message) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)";
    try {
        connection = plugin.getHikari().getConnection();
        // Inserting into the table
        statement = connection.prepareStatement(update);
        // Values
        statement.setString(1, name);
        statement.setString(2, area);
        statement.setString(3, date);
        statement.setString(4, message);
        statement.execute();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: I get the same problem :/ I've updated my code above. Any ideas?

Comment: @Nicster15 . . . Your updated query does not look like this query.  Note:  "INSERT INTO help(name, area, date, message) VALUES" is all a single string.

Answer (score 3):

You are doing the SQL incorrectly. When using preparedstatements, you need to do as follow:

```
String update = "INSERT INTO help (column1, column2, column2, column4) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)";
```

Comment: I get the same problem :/ I've updated my code above. Any ideas?

Comment: Dont use "" on the column names

Comment: Huh? How else can I add the String?

Comment: It should be all ONE string like shown on my answer

Comment: So then how should I insert my other strings?

Comment: The insert syntax is: insert into tableName (columnName1, columnName2) VALUES (?,?). Not sure what you mean by "other strings"

Comment: I mean the "column1, column2," etc. are strings for me. Like: String name = "name";

Comment: If you are trying to concatenate like that, it is better if you use StringBuffer. Try doing it witnout the variables but hardcoding the column names and check if you can get that working

Comment: Do you mind linking me or give me an example. Or somehow to do what Im trying to do and make the first column just increment? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try to replace `String update = "INSERT INTO help(?, ?, ?, ?) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)";`  with

```
 String update = "INSERT INTO help("name","area","date","message") VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)";
    statement.setString(1, name);
    statement.setString(2, area);
    statement.setString(3, date);
    statement.setString(4, message);
```

Comment: I get the same problem :/ I've updated my code above. Any ideas?